# Delete all files, including those within a sub-directory older than 3 months PHP

Tags: php

I have a 'cache' folder on my webserver where .html files are stored, the file structure is as follows:

```
cache > user@gmail.com > several .html files.
```

I need a PHP script that will browse all the subdirectors within the user folders and delete files older than 3 months.

I have this script so far:

```
$DIR = '/cache/';
if ($handle = opendir($DIR)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ( filemtime($DIR.$file) <= time()-60*60*24*120 ) { //120 days?
           unlink($DIR.$file);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

But it does not handle sub-directories. It is also giving me errors because it is trying to unlink directorys..

Update: trying to add a count feature:

```
<?php

rrmdir(/www/deletecontentsofthisfolder/);
echo $count . ' files deleted!';

function rrmdir($dir,$count=0) 
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) 
    {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) 
        {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") 
            {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object,$count);
                if (filemtime($dir."/".$object) <= time()-60*60*24*120) @unlink($dir."/".$object); count++
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        //rmdir($dir);
    }
return $count;
}
```

Comment: Code is not religion, you may try stuff with no risk of going to hell :))

Comment: You could take a look at the [Symfony Filesystem Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) which allows you to remove directories recursively among other things

Comment: Extend it to handle subdirectories, when you get to a problem, ask a question here. This one isn't a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function rrmdir($dir) 
{
    if (is_dir($dir)) 
    {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) 
        {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") 
            {
                if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object);
                if (filemtime($dir."/".$object) <= time()-60*60*24*120) @unlink($dir."/".$object);
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        //rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting ' [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty' error, I'm not trying to remove directorys, just files within them.

Comment: [function.unlink]: Is a directory on line "if (filemtime($dir."/".$object) <= time()-60*60*24*120) unlink($dir."/".$object);"

Comment: can you try now. I added @ to unlink. `@unlink(..`

Comment: I'm trying to add a count function so I can display how many files have been deleted, please check my updated question to see what I have tried, it's not working....

Comment: I fixed your function. can you try now

Comment: Still don't work, I added a ; after count++ as it was giving an error but is returning 0 even after deleting files

Comment: I updated your question. I just add "&" symbol to $count variable.